# How to update subscriber email in MailChimp list (using Gibbon API in Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

In my Ruby on Rails website, whenever user signup, they are automatically added to the mailing list. There is an option where user can update his/her email address. 
And I am trying to use Gibbon gem to make API calls to MailChimp, but unsure how to update email address of the already subscribed user.

I found this documentation from MailChimp which states it is possible to update:
https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash

But the example is given in curl, can anyone guide how to use Gibbon gem in RoR to implement the same?

Appreciate any input.

Comment: As per the API, the closest transformed method in the gem is `gibbon.lists(list_id).members(lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address).upsert(body: {email_address: "foo@bar.com", status: "subscribed", merge_fields: {FNAME: "First Name", LNAME: "Last Name"}})`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna: It helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this video is about gem 'gibbon' connect your ruby on rails app users to your mailchimp account list step by step https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY8v3MQoU3g&t=3s
Let me know if you have any question about it!